# count syntax in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to get the number of rows that satisfies the condition.

```
mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sid WHERE sid='".session_id()."'");
```

this one ignores the condition.

update:

```
$session = session_id();
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as row_count FROM sid WHERE sid = '$session' ";
var_dump($r = mysql_query($sql));//resource(4) of type (mysql result) (1)
var_dump(mysql_fetch_assoc($r));
//array(1) { ["row_count"]=> string(1) "1" }  - this result is OK(2)
```

(1) `resource(4)` - I thought that 4 was the count

(2) `mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['id']);` gives `0`

note:

I have changed from `mysql_num_rows` to this type of getting count because I thought it will return immediately the count and I dont have to write more lines to get this basic data.

Comment: Well it shouldn't - why are you so sure it does?

Comment: Somewhat unrelated: if the `session_id()` can be manipulated by the user in anyway (i.e. comes from a cookie or URL parameter - not a PHP specialist), this code is vulnerable to SQL injection and should be fixed.

Comment: @Romain you make a valid point, although I think that PHP is intelligent enough to spot this/will not allow it anyway, as (at least) `';` are not valid characters in a session id, and if you send an invalid session id, a call to `session_start()` will create a new session and generate a new id. Still +1 for your comment, though, as I'm not 110% sure about this.

Comment: @DaveRandom, the `;` is not a possible vector for SQL-injection attacks. `mysql_query` does not allow multiple queries, the XKCD is incorrect and **that** attack is impossible.  What is possible is a `' or (1=1) UNION SELECT username, password, email FROM users -- ` kind of injection. Of course `'` can be encoded in clever ways. You should never rely on internals, but just escape everything before injecting it into the SQL-statement.

Comment: @Johan Fair enough - I am not that hot on exactly what SQL injection attacks are possible for any given query, so I tend to just escape *everything* (to a possibly unecessary level) but it's nice to see that *some* people have a clue what's going on...

Comment: if `some_id = 0` this will usually generate 0 hits, because id's generally are positive integers >= 1.

Comment: @Johan: in the past, there was a way to have `mysql_query` accept multiple statements. I sure hope it's not the case anymore as this was a horrible, horrible usage pattern.

Comment: @Romain `mysqli_multi_query` can accept multiple statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way of doing this is:

```
$session = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['id']);  <<-- Get the session id
echo "debug: session_id = ".htmlentities($session);
$sql = "SELECT count(*) as row_count FROM tablename WHERE sid = '$session' ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
  die('error in query '.$sql.' error is: '.mysql_error());
}
//we only have 1 result
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
//always sanitize so you don't suffer XSS attacks when the query changes   
//and the $row['x'] changes from an integer to a user-supplied string.
$count = intval($row['row_count']);  
echo "count is: ".$count;
```

The table name and the column name **can** be the same, but in your case they probably are not.
`sid` obviously stands for the field "session_id", so you need to replace the first `sid` after `FROM` with your tablename.

Comment: +1 ...and then (for clarity) `$result = mysql_query($sql); $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); $count = $row['row_count'];`

Answer (score 0):

first write your query in php variable and echo it to check what session_id() returns and then try may be there is nothing in your session_id(); like

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sid WHERE sid='".session_id()."'";
echo $sql;
```

and run it in phpmyadmin if it work than your query is qrite else something is wrong

Answer (score 0):

table name = "sessions"

column name = "sid"

```
mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sessions WHERE sid='".session_id()."'");
```